# Relational Mapping using Peewee

Tags: python, data-modeling, peewee

I'm new to relational databases and I'm quite confused on how should I create the models. What I need need to get done is to filter the posts content through the language choice and to do that I need to create a relational database. My doubt comes when deciding how many models(tables) should I have to accomplish this. Here is an example:

models.py

```
class Post(Model):
    timestamp = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    user = ForeignKeyField(
        rel_model=User,
        related_name='posts'
    )
    language = TextField()
    content = ForeignKeyField(THIS NEEDS TO POINT TO THE LANGUAGE)

    class Meta:
        database = DATABASE
```

Is it possible to accomplish something like this? Should I create more than one Post model?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you run through the quickstart guide? Doing so might give you a feel for how to create models and set up relationships:

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/quickstart.html

To answer your immediate question, you can create another table for language, i.e.

```
class Language(Model):
    name = CharField()

    class Meta:
        database = DATABASE
```

So all together you'd have (cleaned up a bit):

```
DATABASE = SqliteDatabase('mydb.db') # or PostgresqlDatabase or MySQLDatabase

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = DATABASE

class User(BaseModel):
    email = CharField()
    # whatever other user fields

class Language(BaseModel):
    name = CharField()
    # other fields?

class Post(BaseModel):
    timestamp = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    user = ForeignKeyField(User, related_name='posts')
    language = TextField()
    content = ForeignKeyField(Language, related_name='posts')
```

Comment: I've read the docs but I wasn't sure on how this has to be made. Your answer will help other people that have the same doubt I had until now. Thanks buddy!